# open .dat file in R similar to joblib in python

Tags: r, joblib

I want to read .dat file in R, `data.dat` contains two list of lists `(a,b)` with dimensions as `50*5000*30` and `50*5000*5` respectively. `a` contains values between `0` and `1024` and `b` contains values between `0` and `1`.

**1st Attempt**:

```
#install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("insysbio/dbs-package")
library("dbs")
file_path = system.file(package = "dbs", "data.dat")
raw_data = read.dat(file_path)
data = import.dat(raw_data)
```

**Error**

```
data = import.dat(raw_data)
Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset), vars, drop = drop] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

**2nd Attempt**:

```
> read.table("data.dat", fileEncoding="latin1")
```

**Error** Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 2 did not have 3 elements

**3rd Attempt**:

```
data = scan(file="data.dat", what=list(x="", y="", z=""), flush=TRUE)
```

**output**
3 lists are read but with garbage values

I can open the file in **Python** by following:

```
import joblib
a, b = joblib.load("data.dat")
```

Is there any alternative to joblib in R?

Comment: The joblib `dat` files seem to be specific to *joblib*, and generated using Python’s binary object serialisation. I’m not aware of a port of this mechanism to R (because its utility would be limited). If you want to have an *equivalent* in R, look at `readRDS` and `saveRDS`. If you want to share binary data between R and Python, have a look at Apache Arrow.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I dont want to share binary data between R and Python. I want to read the .dat file in R

Comment: Well where does the `.dat` file come from? From joblib? Then that sounds like you *do* want to share data, in which case — look at the suggestions; or try out the ‘reticulate’ package. In general, `.dat` isn’t a standard format: it’s just an arbitrary file extension. *Anything* can name its files `.dat`, this doesn’t tell us how to read the files. The `.dat` format used by the ‘dbs’ package has nothing to do with the `.dat` file used by Python’s joblib.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for your guidance. I successfully used reticulate package to read the data in R. I answered the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reticulate package provides an R interface to Python modules, classes, and functions.

```
#install.packages("reticulate")
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")
use_virtualenv("myenv")
use_condaenv("myenv")
py_config()

#to install the required packages in python file
run_python_file <- function(python_file){
  a = try(reticulate::py_run_file(python_file),silent=TRUE)
  if(inherits(a,"try-error")& grepl("ModuleNotFoundError",a)){
    system(sprintf("python -m pip install %s",gsub(".* |\\W","",c(a))))
    run_python_file(python_file)
  }
  else a
}
data  = run_python_file("readfile.py")

data$a
data$b
```

**readfile.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import joblib
a, b = joblib.load("data.dat")
```